# Заполнение данных из файла в массив

Tags: c++

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    fstream file("src");

    if (file.is_open()) {
        int a, count = 0 ;

        while (!file.eof()) {
            file >> a;  
            count++;
        }
        file.clear();
        file.seekg(0);

        int **A = new int*[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)A[i] = new int[count];

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                file >> A[i][j]; 
            }
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
                cout <<  A[i][j] << endl;
            }
            cout << endl; 
        }
    }
    system("pause"); 
    return 0;
}
```

Заполняю данные из файла в матрицу .
Сначала выводятся все данные из файла , а потом выводится -842150451
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так понятно, у вас всего записей сount (наверно, 20), а вы хотите во втором цикле count * count записывать, а потом считывать

Comment: Столько в файле просто нет, вот и неинициализированная память